# getJSON prints unicode characters as mojibake (Windows-1252)

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, unicode, mojibake

Here's the deal. I'm trying to make a chat-like application that works with MySQL.
Messages are stored in the database, and retrieved with JSON.

With .getJSON i print it to the div element which is used as a mailbox. I use 1s interval to check for messages and refresh. Here is the code which retrieves JSON:

```
setInterval(function() { 
    $.getJSON("inbox.php?<?php echo $_SESSION['connect']; ?>", function(data) {     
        if(data.length > 0) {
            var str = "";
            $.each(data, function(k, v) {               
                str += "<div class='inbox'>(" + v.time_trace + ") " + v.name + ": " + v.message + "</div>";
            });
            $("#messages").html(str);
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

And it's all working fine, except...

**When I send a unicode message, specifically a Cyrillic one, I get mojibake in Windows-1252 when jQuery uses that timer/interval. All the previous messages get garbled, until I refresh the whole page from the browser, and than it looks fine, shows UTF-8.** That kinda looks like this:

```
Ð�ÐµÐ³Ð¾Ñ� Ñ�Ð¸Ð»Ð° Ñ�Ñ�Ð¿Ñ�ÐºÐ°.
```

If i disable the timer, and refresh myself I get good messages, but I need it to automatically check.
HTML is set to UTF-8, and the DB is set to utf8_general_ci.

I really think that it has something to do with either getJSON, or something crazy like file encoding.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you setting the character set of the mysql connection? (`SET NAMES utf8`).

Comment: Yes, I do. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: Hm, what kind of headers does this send? `Content-Type: text/json; character-set=utf-8;`, or something else?

Comment: What does your code for return the JSON look like? Are you using standard `json_encode()`? If so, that encodes all non-ASCII to ASCII-safe escapes, so the corruption would have had to occur before being returned as JSON. If you have `encode_utf8()` anywhere that would explain it.

Comment: PS. Don't work with pasting together markup strings like that, you're giving yourself cross-site-scripting vulnerabilities. Use `.text()`, `.attr()` and the element creation shortcuts instead of setting HTML markup. eg. `$('<div class="inbox">', {text: '('+v.time_trace+') '+v.name+': '+v.message}).appendTo('#messages');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by removing htmlspecialchars I've been using in another part of the code. That made the mess. Thank you for the markup strings note, I appreciate it.